# Adding a CMD linebreak in Python

Tags: python

How would I add a CMD line break in Python?
I have tried the following, but it still comes out as a paragraph.

```
print "Welcome to xbrEra's first application";
print
print " using Python 2.7.1. I hope you enjoy";
print
print "-------------------------------------";
print
```

Comment: What is a CMD linebreak??? Apart from that: the ';' is completely needless - Python is not Java

Comment: I'd suggest reading a Python book before attempting any programming ^^;

Comment: A linebreak, press enter. And I am working in a CMD box. My version of Python requires ";" or it brings up a syntax error.

Comment: your version of Python requires ';' - truly nonsense - which version should that be. Python *never* required ; as line-ending -

Comment: @Andreas I sincerely apologize. It turns out I had installed Perl and I thought Python had already been installed due to the error it came up with on the installer. The error on the installer was actually my antivirus being an imbecile and blocking some of it's rights without notifying me of that current situation. Sorry again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

depending on your OS:

```
print "\n"
```

or

```
print "\r\n"
```

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary, "print" automatically outputs a newline after the string

Comment: @Joril no clue what I did, but I installed ActivePerl. Wait, I understand. I'm coding in Perl. Python 2.7.1 and 3.2 both came up with an error that they could not access Windows Installer service.

Answer (score 2):

Python's print stmt adds a `newline` (which may be '\r\n' or '\n' depending upon your OS) automatically. If you don't want the newline to be added, you can end the your print stmt with a comma. Like `print "hello,world",` And you can explicitly add newline control characters in your string to have that effect too.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want control over how a block of plain text is formatted, use triple-quoted strings.

```
print """
Welcome to xbrEra's first application
 using Python 2.7.1. I hope you enjoy
-------------------------------------
"""
```